# Cannot connect to the api when the site uses cloudflare

Tags: php, cloudflare

I have a service site that also offers an api.

But my site users can not use the api, because the site is connected to cloudflare!

I connected to my site via file_get_contents, but got an error

That means I connected **mywebsite.com/test.php** to **mywebsite.com/api/v2** ...

I got this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Peer certificate CN=`amazeservice.net' did not match expected CN=`mywebsite.com' in /home/mywebsite/public_html/test.php on line 3

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/mywebsite/public_html/test.php on line 3

Warning: file_get_contents(https://mywebsite.com/api/v2): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/mywebsite/public_html/test.php on line 3
```

I tried to ask this question in my cloudflare forum, but I do not know why it is not possible to post a question.

Comment: What version of PHP and OpenSSL are you using on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Now, Cloudflare API Security products are available to Enterprise customers only.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/api-shield/